# try to connect hosted web application to local database?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, odbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect hosted webs application to Local database. First I was getting  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()` error but after add the "odbc" extension i started getting

`Error connecting to the ODBC database: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`

I used the following code in php script to connect to the Local database using ODBC

```
$odbc['dsn'] = "SageLine50v19";
$odbc['user'] = "Peac";
$odbc['pass'] = "XXXX";
$mysql['host'] = "localhost";
$mysql['user'] = "root";
$mysql['pass'] = "";
$mysql['dbname'] = "sagetest";
$mysql['idfield'] = "id";


// Step 1: Connect to the source ODBC database
if ($debug) echo "Connect to " . $odbc['dsn'] . ' as ' . $odbc['user'] . "\n";
$conn = odbc_connect($odbc['dsn'], $odbc['user'], $odbc['pass']);
if (!$conn) {
die("Error connecting to the ODBC database: " . odbc_errormsg());
}

// loop through each table 
$allTables = odbc_tables($conn);
$tablesArray = array();
while (odbc_fetch_row($allTables)) {
 if (odbc_result($allTables, "TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE") {
    $tablesArray[] = odbc_result($allTables, "TABLE_NAME");
 }
}
 //print_r($tablesArray);      // to list all tables
```

My ***ODBC.ini*** looks like below

```
[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
t=SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (32 bit)
SageLine50v19=Pervasive ODBC Client Interface (32 bit)

[t]
Driver32=C:\Windows\system32\sqlncli10.dll
[SageLine50v19]
Driver32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error connecting to the ODBC database: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data
>   source **name not found**, and no default driver specified

**Problem:**

This is your data source name:

```
[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
```

But in your php you put

```
$odbc['dsn'] = "SageLine50v19";
```

**Solution:**

Decide wich one you change:

**odbc.ini**

```
[SageLine50v19]
```

or **php**

```
$odbc['dsn'] = "ODBC 32 bit Data Sources";
```

Comment: thanks so much @meda! you are correct but here is the thing i want to accomplish the php code is on my webserver and i am trying to access mysql database in my local. how can i fix this issue. do you think is this possible or is there any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes of course add another as many entry to the odbc just create one more [localshostdsn] then point it to localhost

Comment: thanks!! i did and now odbc.ini looks like this`[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
t=SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (32 bit)
SageLine50v19=Pervasive ODBC Client Interface (32 bit)
ODBC 32 bit Data Sources=Pervasive ODBC Client Interface (32 bit)
Driver32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll
localshostdsn=Pervasive ODBC Client Interface (32 bit)
[t]
Driver32=C:\Windows\system32\sqlncli10.dll
[SageLine50v19]
Driver32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll
[localshostdsn]
Driver32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll`

Comment: not really :(. What is the purpose of adding new dsn `[localshostdsn] ` and  can you explain me what you mean by "add another as many entry  to the odbc", what will be the next step after adding `localshostdsn` . i put the content of odbc.ini on the previous comment. i used `$odbc['dsn'] = "ODBC 32 bit Data Sources";`

Comment: Oh wait did you say the code is on the server, then how can you access your local db from there. Thats not possible

Comment: it sound weird but thats what am trying to do. it looks like there is a way but i couldn't find any resource

Comment: Your PC will need to be exposed to the public internet, what are u using xampp?

Comment: Do you have a public internet ip? Or perhaps you can achieve this with a VPN

Comment: But you didnt say why you want to do that, its not usual im sure there is a workaround

Comment: Yes you mean internet ip right?. but the thing is im trying to get data from local database as an array and sync to third party app. the php code i am using is used something like API.

Comment: ODBC connection works on local machine works fine on VPN as well im able to access data from office database throught VPN - ODBC - using the same PHP code

Comment: Ok so if you have vpn, you can put the private ip in the dsn

Comment: Still getting the same error. but successfully connected to my office database

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what platform is this on?

Given unixODBC I would expect Unix/Linux. But the drivers being .dll's indicate Windows. Which one is it?

If the driver manager tries to load a lib and fails, it will give the "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified" (thats what the spec insists it does), if you are trying to use windows drivers on Unix, then I would expect it to fail to load.